# Does probability describe our understanding of an event or the actual mechanics of the event?

Tags: probability

If you toss a coin so that it only flips over once before landing we would not consider that to be a fair toss. If the coin is tossed again so it flips hundreds of times then it would be considered a fair toss. But the only difference between these two situations is our state of knowledge. Both coin tosses obey the same mechanical laws. It's just the that the first toss is more humanly predictable than the second. So, is 'probability' a measure of 'what we know' or a description of a physical event?

Answer (score 0):

[Probability theory is the theory of plausible conclusions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/591867/362671). It gives us a set of unique, consistent rules for degrees of plausibility to be represented by real numbers in correspondence with **common sense**. See Jaynes' treatment of the [same](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/probability-theory/9CA08E224FF30123304E6D8935CF1A99).

"What we know" aka the *a priori* beliefs aren't overlooked. See [Bayesian](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_probability) treatment which is in same league with that of Jaynes.

Comment: Edwin Thompson *Jaynes*. But his views were often seen as unconventional even among Bayesians

Comment: Thanks @Henry. It's the autocorrect wonder of the phone.

Answer (score 0):

When we say "toss a fair coin", it is a assumed, that the two sides are symmetric, and the person who is throwing the coin is not intentionally trying to make it land on one side or another. Therefore, we describe the random experiment as the sample space $\{ H, T\}$, where each outcome is equally likely.

This is the idealized mathematical scenario. You might argue that there were instances of coin tossing where this idealized approach was violated. But then it just means that this probability model does not suit that particular experiment.

The probability models we write down are idealized scenarios (often simpler) of what we think happens. Maybe sometimes the experiment does not behave the way that we thought. However, in mathematics, one assumes a particular model, and then draws conclusions from there. In statistics, one might rather be interested to see how well a real life experiment fits some idealized mathematical model.